# How to create native api call for 'bulkCopy' action to create copy of the task with options similar to UI in attask?

Tags: attask

I am trying to compose Api call to copy one task from one project to another project, with all the options similar to UI. but below url is not working. 
I tried POST as well as PUT request.

1# 
https://example-attaskurl.com/attask/api-internal/task/bulkCopy?taskIDs=57a857e5000......&projectID=573.....

2# 
https://example-attaskurl.com/attask/api/TASK/bulkCopy?updates={"taskIDs":["5790c67f0001d3d5176e....."],"projectID":"578636c2000e62292ec4c..."}&sessionID=1deb155795d149379d....

Following is the error message:

```
{`enter code here`
"error": {
"class": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
"message": "unrecognized URI format: too many parts"
}-
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v5.0/task?apiKey=&method=PUT&updates={"taskIDs": ["57cc337b0252f39d47a2ddc0e994af98","57cc33730252f356c7b701e4005820f5" ],"projectID": "56d8b69f0077e4db6bdb89c9288ec11c" }&action=bulkCopy

The method does need to be "put". I have had better luck using the action=bulkCopy instead of putting /task/bulkCopy in the URL. Then just make sure your JSON is properly encoded.

I'm using an API key here, but it should work fine with a sessionID.

Somewhat related, if you are not using Postman (free Chrome extension) already, check it out. It make messing around with API calls a lot easier.